# Updating an object within a List of objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0

I have a function which goes like this

```
public class Component
{
  public List<SubComponent1> subComponent1 {get;set;}
  public List<SubComponent2> subComponent2 {get;set;}
}


public void Update()
{
  List<Component> collection = new List<Component> collection();

  //populate from service
  collection = getData();

  //I want to update subComponent1 
  List<SubComponent1> copycomp = null;

  copycomp = collection.subComponent1;

  UpdateService1Data(ref copycomp);

 }

public void UpdateService1Data(ref List<SubComponent1> subcopy)
{
  //Do some operations and update SubComponent1
   //Changes will reflect in collection object
}
```

My question goes like this:

In the `Update()` function `copycomp` is referring to the object within `collection` variable, so any changes made to the `copycomp` variable doesn't need to assign it back to the collection like this :

```
service.subComponent1 = copycomp ;
```

since it is a class type and referring to the same object.

But I am passing the same reference to `UpdateService1Data()` , then why do I need to make use of **ref** keyword? Why can't I just pass the variable? If updating works in **Update** function then why can't it work in **UpdateService1Data**() . I am visualizing it as the reference or the address to the **SubComponent1** class is passed everywhere copycomp is used?

Comment: I think you can use it without the ref keyword, but I think it depends on the changes you're making in UpdateService1Data method.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. It won't even compile. Please share a working version so we can help.

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer : Do not give heeds to the compilation of code . I cant populate the real service data. I have made it simple for understanding purpose to highlight on the concepts.

Comment: You only need `ref` if you are going to set `subcopy = new List<SubComponent1>()` inside `UpdateService1Data`. Simple as that. Otherwise, there's no need.

Comment: The collection object is of type List<Component>, and then you are trying to access the subComponent1 property on the collection object. I understand the mock service, but I can't make sense of how this error works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Update() function copycomp is referring to the object within
>   collection variable, so any changes made to the copycomp variable
>   doesn't need to assign it back to the collection like this :

The value of `copycomp` is a reference to the object `collection.subComponent1`, which is a `List<SubComponent1>`. When you call a method and pass `copycomp` as an argument (without the use of `ref`) you actually pass a *copy of this reference*, this is the default behavior in C# and in many other high level programming languages. Hence you still have a reference to the original object and you can alter any value there. Specifically in your case you can remove items from the list, add other items, change the value of a property of an item etc.

If the above is that you want you don't need the `ref` keyword. You should use the `ref` keyword if you want to change the reference that `copycomp` holds and then use the new reference for another purpose. In this case you could do any of the actions mentioned previously, which would result in the mutation of the object state that `copycomp` points to and in addition to this you could change even the actual reference that `copycomp` holds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the accepted answer for [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).  But the short version is that out and ref are required when (and only when) you want to make it possible to change the variable/field that is used as an argument to the method.

You might think of it as a closure that can’t outlast the calling method.

In your case, if you want UpdateService1Data to be able to **mutate** the list collection.subComponent1 then it doesn’t need to be ref or out. If you want to be able to make the variable copycomp refer to an entirely different list (or null) then it needs to have a ref or out parameter.

Again, passing by reference means “able to change a variable in the calling method”, if you don’t want to do that you shouldn’t use it.